# Angular: trigger a data list (onKeyDown) inside a text area

Tags: angular, keyevent, datalist

The idea is simple: trigger an autocomplete on keydown inside a text area, so the user gets help when choosing a name. If I do something like this:

HTML

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
          <textarea rows="8" class="form-control top-dist " list="employees" name="employees" (keydown)='eventHandler($event)'
            type="text" placeholder="Add Post" [(ngModel)]="posts.body" name="body">

          </textarea>
          <div *ngIf="list">
            <ul *ngFor="let name of postName">
              <li>{{name.name}}</li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
@HostListener("window:keydown", ["$event"])

  eventHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 65) {
      this.list=true;
    }
  }
```

it works, I can see the list of employees when I press the key "a". But I dont see the list (autocomplete) when I try this aproach:

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
          <textarea rows="8" class="form-control top-dist " list="employees" name="employees" (keydown)='eventHandler($event)'
            type="text" placeholder="Add Post" [(ngModel)]="posts.body" name="body">

          </textarea>
          <datalist *ngIf="list" id="employees">
            <option *ngFor="let name of postName" [value]="name.name">

          </datalist>
        </div>
```

(the TS is the same). So what am I doing wrong? Can someone point me the right direction?

Comment: in .ts file, is `eventHandler` inside of `@HostListener`? If so, remove the `@HostListener` and just have the `eventHandler` function.

Comment: no, its outside the @HostListner. But without it i cannot see the names on the li's

Comment: anyone, please?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** 
`<option>` tag is not even closed. See reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

EDIT: I haven't noticed it earlier, but you use `textarea` with `datalist` and `datalist` works with `input` only, see reference [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element)

You should use it as `<option [value]="name.name">Display text</option>`

**Offtopic tips:**
Looking at your code I have noticed few things that you might take in consider. You really don't need to listen keyevents here. I think the best condition for your `*ngIf` will be just `posts.body.length > 0`.

Also, you might want to read about:

- [FormGroups](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)
- Two way data binding is not the best option, you should avoid it

Comment: thank you for your answer and tips, but still, closing the option tag didnt fixed the problem. I'm doing an exercise where this is one the requirements. As you press a certain key, an auto complete of that data should popup, so I really need the listner to check. Am I right?

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that key must be specific one. :) 

I just have realized that you use `textarea`. `datalist` works with `input` only, and that's by design (see w3 definition [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element) ). If you want to use have same feature with textarea you should use JavaScript.